# How to merge data in 2 csv files using shell script

Tags: shell, csv

csv1:

```
StoreID    Emailcount

2000           3

2001           2
```

csv2:

```
StoreID    Slotcount

2000           100

2001           120
```

Output required as below

```
StoreID    Emailcount     Slotcount

2000           3             100

2001           2             120
```

Can you please help me to resolve my issue?

Comment: Did you attempt to write a shell script? BTW I would personally write a Python script rather than a shell script.

Comment: search here for examples of the `join` command. It is designed for such problems, but assumes the data will be sorted by the `key` used to `join` the files. Assuming sorted files, your command will be 20 chars or less, plust the file names and it runs as a standalong c-program, without the "cost" of starting an interpreter. Good luck.

Comment: @jarmod yes you are right, with Python script it is easy to do. But the requirement is to do with shell script only.

Comment: Sure @shellter i will try to use ```join```, thanks